# Use ASP.NET in a way similar to PHP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been using PHP for a long time, but I want to move to C#. However, I don't care much for web controls and the template system. Don't get me wrong, it is good for many projects, but not all. Sometimes I want to use my own template system

I just want to run my code on every page request and print some HTML, CSS or whatever. Just something like Response.Write() or PHPs "echo" without all the templates and controls. What is the best way to achieve this?

Edit:

This is how I would like it to work:

```
private void Page_Request(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do my stuff here

    Response.Write(myhtml);
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this? http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

Comment: In that case, it seems like you would want to use ASP.NET web forms. www.asp.net/web-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be as bare bones as possible, you could use generic handlers (.ashx).

You can register routes in your web.config file, to direct the request to the appropriate handler.

I wouldn't recommend this approach though. Seems like a lot of extra work (you will need to write everything to the response), and will be prone to errors when you want to make changes.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I want, just handle the request with the least amount of complexity. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The MVC framework is probably your best bet. It doesn't have the web control aspect. Probably not exactly what you're after (from the template point of view - if I understand what you mean by template that is) but it's close.

http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: I have looked at the MVC framework and I like it, but it's not exactly what I am looking for. There is still too much fuzz. I want to write my own router and templating system. Basically I want the least amount of framework and just access to all data relating to the request and then print my own response.

Comment: I *think* you can write your own templating engine with MVC, though I am unsure of the amount of effort that would be involved. The MVC framework is as barebones as it gets in terms of asp.net, as far as I know.